# Multiselection mode doesn't end automatically when I click Delete

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm working on a "small" example to learn about multiselect mode for a `ListView`. I set the mode on my list:

```
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE_MODAL);
        listView.setMultiChoiceModeListener(new MultiChoiceModeListener(this));
    }
```

Inflate the menu:

```
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = activity.getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.context, menu);
    return true;
}
```

And handle the menu event:

```
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.delete_menu:
            activity.deleteSelectedWords();
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Is there something else I need to do to end the action mode and return to the normal action bar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `clearChoices()` on the `ListView`, as that should exit the action mode. Do this after you do your `activity.deleteSelectedWords()` bit. See [this sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ActionMode/ActionModeMC) for a complete working implementation.

Or, call `finish()` on the `ActionMode` itself.

Comment: I'm working from the code snippets in your book. `clearChoices()` doesn't seem to work. I guess I have to call `finish()` manually.

Comment: For future readers, calling `finish()` manually does the trick.